# problem in repairing software center

Tags: 11.10, software-center, package-management

what should be done regarding this error(software center) -

```
installArchives() failed: Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.

Extracting templates from packages: 90%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.

Extracting templates from packages: 90%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.

Extracting templates from packages: 90%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
```

this error is repeating whenever i am repairing software center.

I'm having problems with my software center .. when i want to install some package that following message it appears

```
"items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired. do you want to repair it now?"
```

after i click Repair, another window pops up, saying :

```
"Package operation fails - The installation or removal of a software package failed"
```

I click repair, and a few seconds later, it pops up again!!!! no matter how many times i click repair, nothing happens.

Also .. I've Another Problem With Update Manager That Shows Me The Following Message:

"

```
the package system is broken. Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f"
```

also, i tried sudo apt-get install -f 
i got this error...

```
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Please provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

There are reports out that libc6 broke the package manager in 11.10, see here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/193006

A proper workaround is described on Ubuntu Forum here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11767830&postcount=19